# Dart error: type 'Options' is not loaded

Tags: dart

I'm trying to get started with Dart, and cannot figure out how to read shell arguments. As far as I can tell from other questions, this should work:

```dart
#!/usr/bin/env /path/to/dart/dart-sdk/bin/dart

main()
{
  print(new Options().arguments);
}
```

But I get an error "type 'Options' is not loaded":

```dart
Unhandled exception:
'file:///path/to/script.dart': Error: line 5 pos 13: type 'Options' is not loaded
  print(new Options().arguments);
            ^
malformed type used.
#0      main (file:///path/to/script.dart:5:13)
```

What am I doing wrong?

I'm using the current stable version of dart (downloaded today) on Mac OS X 10.8.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Due to a recent change in the library (the `Options` class is no more), the correct answer is:

```
import 'dart:io';

main() {
  print(Platform.executableArguments);
}
```

Most of the Options functionality has moved to the new Platform class in `dart:io`.

Answer (score 4):

Options has moved to dart:io. Add the following:

```dart
#!/usr/bin/env /path/to/dart/dart-sdk/bin/dart

import 'dart:io';

main()
{
  print(new Options().arguments);
}
```